# Using SubModules on AppHarbor

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, appharbor

I know that current Git submodules are not supported by AppHarbor (as per [this support ticket](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/tips-and-tricks/git-requirements) and I just did a quick test that confirmed it)

BUT, is there another way?

I currently have a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/TeamMentor-OWASP/appHarbour) that I want to use as my submodule's remote master, and I need to create a number of other GitHub repositories that use this codebase (with the only changes happening inside the App_Data contents).

Using a Git submodule seems like a perfect solution, BUT, of course that problem is that its contents will not be deployed to AppHarbour.

So apart from creating a hard-copy (on the file system) of the master GitGub Repository, is there another alternative?

Comment: I'm using Nuget Packages that are restored to the websites that use them. But this is requiring me to be running something that autogenerates the nuget packages (TeamCity). I'm not sure if this can be used to fake what you are talking about, but is an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually found a better way to do this using Git SubTree Merge. That works much better than submodules,  since I do want to be able to:

- have the local (merged) files there
- be able to make changes to then
- have the full history of the original repositories.

Here are more details about Git's subtree merge:

- http://help.github.com/subtree-merge/
- http://progit.org/book/ch6-7.html

Answer (score 0):

set up a second repo so you don't bloat yours with the binaries. Merge in your app into that repo and push from there.

You could also use that repo to "unsubmodule" your dependencies with a short script.