# How do I share code between 2 (or more) AppHarbor sites?

Tags: git, appharbor

I currently have two git repos and two sites deployed on AppHarbor. All works fine. Problem is that both sites share quite a few things between them and it is a pain to duplicate the work between them and ensure that they are up to date.

What would be ideal is having a single git repo with two VS solutions. One for each site. Then I could extract the common elements and share the code between the different sites.

Is there a way to tell AppHarbor to use a specific solution file? And share a git repo between two sites?

Is there some other way that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the [getting started docs](http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/build-process-and-solution-file-convention) for information about the build convention and solution naming.

And Yes, you can create a single git repository with separated solutions for the sites you want share the same code, just remember to setup a solution for each web application with the same name of the "slug" of the appharbor application.

For instance:

app1.apphb.com => app1.sln

app2.apphb.com => app2.sln

@alastairtree,  Currently, AppHarbor doesn't support submodules, so, we must use subtree instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the shared code in a third repo and use git sub-modules to embed the shared code into directories in the 2 main ones?

See http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule

Comment: Thanks Alastair, I will have to research whether sub-modules would work.

Comment: Looking at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229984/using-submodules-on-appharbor) and the accepted answer, it looks like subtree merge is a good fit.